# Only system sounds play through laptop speakers - other sound works via HDMI

Tags: sound

I am new to Linux and have given Ubuntu a try. My laptop will play system sounds and test sounds but won't play sounds on videos and spotify etc through the speakers. Sound does however work through the TV when connected via HDMI cable.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please install [PulseAudio Volume Control](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) and use it to verify, that these applications (“sink-sources”) forward their sound to the right audio device (“sink”) – [example screenshot](http://community.linuxmint.com/img/screenshots/pavucontrol.png).

Comment: type pavucontrol in the terminal, from here you have the control you need

Answer (score 2):

I've found that sometimes running `mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old/` in a terminal followed by logging out & in fixes things (this backs up, deletes & resets the configuration for pulseaudio, the program that manages sound on Ubuntu).

Comment: this didnt help me, I used pavucontrol in the terminal